# Como aparecer overflow-x

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, css3, responsive

Construí una tabla adaptativa con Bootstrap, usando el siguiente código:

```
<div class="table-responsive"> 
  <table class="table table-striped">
     ...
  </table>
</div>
```

Pero no aparece el `overflow-x` dentro de mi tabla. ¿Por qué sucede esto? Estoy en Chrome.

Comment: ¿La tabla excede el ancho de la pantalla? ¿El contenido de las celdas se rompe en líneas?

Answer (score 2):

Te falta añadir una clase al `<div>` que contiene la tabla: `.text-nowrap`. Con la clase `.text-nowrap` especificas cómo se van a comportar los espacios en blanco dentro de la tabla.

Si no especificas la clase, el contenido de las celdas se distribuirá en múltiples líneas. Al ponerla, el texto no saltará de línea (*no wrap*) y causará que se vea la barra de scroll horizontal:

```
<div class="table-responsive text-nowrap"> 
  <table class="table table-striped">
     ...
  </table>
</div>
```

Para más información y ejemplos, puedes ver [la documentación de MD Bootstrap](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/tables/responsive/#columns-with-text-no-wrap).

Comment: gracias por la ayuda pero yo quiero que aparezca overflow-x para desplazar mi tabla horizontalmente. En movil va genial , pero en ordenador solo se puede desplazar con el boton de en medio

Comment: @BrayanCenturiónTorres revisa la doc oficial aquí https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/text/#text-wrapping-and-overflow